# Unexpected token function in node callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax, callback, syntax-error

I'm really new to node and callbacks. I'm working on a Nodeschool problem: to return the data of three given URLs in order using callbacks. I put the results of the three URLs in an object, to keep track of them in order. However I keep failing the tests because, I think, the URL object is being returned before I put all the URLs in it.

TLDR:

Here's the offending function. It keeps telling me "SyntaxError: Unexpected token function." But when I put `console.log(urlObj[url])` into its own function and called it by name in `storeUrl`, I don't think it was run after the `if` statements...

```
function storeUrl(url, info, function(url) {
    // Only log after all the checking is done
    console.log(urlObj[url]);
} ){
// add data to a dict? or something? 
// to keep track of them???
if(url == url1){
    urlObj[url1] = info;
}

if(url == url2){
    urlObj[url2] = info;
}

if(url == url3){
    urlObj[url3] = info;
}

}
```

Here is my entire file:

```
var http = require('http');
var bl = require('bl');
var url1 = process.argv[2];
var url2 = process.argv[3];
var url3 = process.argv[4];
var urlObj = {};
urlObj[url1] = '';
urlObj[url2] = '';
urlObj[url3] = '';


function firstUrl(callback, callback){
    getHttp(url1);
    callback(url2);
    callback(url3);
}

function startItOff(){
    firstUrl(function secondUrl(contents){
    getHttp(contents);
    }, function thirdUrl(contents){
    getHttp(contents);
    });

    // This is what I ultimately want: 
    // A log of the data of each URL, in order, on its own line:
    for (item in urlObj){
        console.log(urlObj[item]);
    }
}

//////////////
// Above this line is ok,
// now trying to retrieve the url only after 
// getting the right one. The getHttp shows
// them in the right order, but retrieveHttp
// doesn't have an order to it.
/////////////

function getHttp(url){

    middleman(url, retrieveHttp);

}

function middleman(url, callback){
    callback(url);
}

function retrieveHttp(url){


    http.get(url, function(res){

    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.pipe(bl(function(err,data){
        if (err) return Error('Error');
        storeUrl(url, data.toString(), callback);

    }));

    });
}

function storeUrl(url, info, function(url) {
    console.log(urlObj[url]);
} ){
    // add data to a dict? or something? 
    // to keep track of them???
    if(url == url1){
    urlObj[url1] = info;
    }

    if(url == url2){
    urlObj[url2] = info;
    }

    if(url == url3){
    urlObj[url3] = info;
    }

    // Also trying to log the data from the URLs here:
    console.log(urlObj[url1]);

}

startItOff();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is a syntax error:

```
function storeUrl(url, info, function(url) {
// Only log after all the checking is done -->
```

So when Node says its a syntax error, its not lying :).  When you are defining the arguments to a function which is what you are doing there, you can't include the word function.

This would be valid syntax:

```
function storeUrl(url, info, callback) {
  console.log(url);
  callback();
}
```

I recommend not trying to learn Node and Javascript at the same time.  Learn Javascript basics and debugging, then callbacks, then tackle Node.

Comment: How come something like this works?:

    `fs.readFile('movie.mp4', function finishedReading(error, movieData) { 

      if (error) return console.error(error)

      // do something with the movieData

    })`

Comment: Because you're not defining arguments there, you are specifying callback code.  The storeUrl line starts with `function` where your example starts with the `readFile` call.  It is confusing when you are starting out.  Normally for callbacks you wouldn't specify a name.  So you could leave `finishedReading` out there.